# What is input#submit?

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS3 and HTML5 from John Duckett's 'HTML & CSS' book. I came across this CSS code:

```css
input#submit{
color: #444444;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #ffffff;
border-bottom: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
background-color: #b9e4e3;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

I know that `#submit` is an id selector but I have not assigned any id to the `input` in above code then how does the `input#submit` worked
and also, if I remove `#submit` the look of button changes,Why?

Comment: it is like `input` type of the selector `submit`. kind of parent child relation.

Comment: Your code works correctly. If you add id `submit` to the input, you will see the difference

Comment: what do you mean by `input` type of the selector `submit`?

Comment: Your analysis is correct. But the code does not work—as you already predict.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about basic selectors

```
input {
    ...
}
```

styles all elements that are of `input` type. While

```
input#submit {
    ...
}
```

styles all inputs with the id attribute of `submit`.

See:

```css
input#submit{
color: #444444;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #ffffff;
border-bottom: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
background-color: #b9e4e3;
}

/*attribute css selector*/
input[type="submit"] {
color: white;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #ffffff;
border-bottom: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
background-color: blue;
}

/*element selector*/
input {
color: white;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #ffffff;
border-bottom: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p>This will be styled be the id selector input#submit</p>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
<p>This will be styled by the attribute selector input[type="submit"]</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit 2">
<br />
<p>This will be styled by input element selector</p>
<input type="button" value="Submit 3">
```

Removing `#submit` from your selector finds the input button to style it. Also, if you add id="submit" to the input button it will get the same styles. Probably hit up [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) to learn about CSS, selectors, etc.

Comment: I was such a fool I got confused on the basic stuff and just asked the question. Thank you for your help